# UpdatePanel with SharePoint 2010 web part

Tags: web-part, ajax, ajax-control-tookit

**UPDATE**

```
  protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            if (!this._error)
            {
                try
                {
                    base.CreateChildControls();

                    UpdatePanel updatePanel1 = new UpdatePanel();
                    updatePanel1.ID = "udpItemListingWebPart";
                    updatePanel1.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;

                    ContentService_VWPUserControl control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath) as MyUserControl_VWPUserControl; 

                    if (control != null)
                        control.WebPart = this;
                    //Controls.Add(control);
                    updatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(control);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    this.HandleException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

**END UPDATE**

the below code is suppose to work but somehow if i have UpdatePanel then it does not render... no error nothing just dont render the web site in my case (http://www.cnn.com) any help?

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{

 base.OnPreRender(e);

UpdatePanel updatePanel1 = new UpdatePanel();
updatePanel1.ID = "udpItemListingWebPart";
updatePanel1.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional; 
PageViewerWebPart oWebPart = new PageViewerWebPart();
oWebPart.ContentLink = "http://www.cnn.com"; 
updatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(oWebPart);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

finally i figured out and below is the updated code: hope this will help others..

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            if (!this._error)
            {
                try
                {
                    base.CreateChildControls();

                    UpdatePanel updatePanel1 = new UpdatePanel();
                    updatePanel1.ID = "udpItemListingWebPart";
                    updatePanel1.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;

                    ContentService_VWPUserControl control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath) as MyUserControl_VWPUserControl; 

                    if (control != null)
                        control.WebPart = this;
                    //Controls.Add(control);
                    updatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(control);
                    this.Controls.Add(updatePanel1);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    this.HandleException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the updatepanel in CreateChildControls instead of prerender and add it to the controls collection for it to work correctly.

Comment: i changed it to `CreateChildControls` still the same, I have updated my question